# Property of median of probability distributiom

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, median

Suppose that a random variable $\mathbb{X}$ has density $f$ and a unique median $m$ . Suppose that $b$ is
any real number.

Show that $\mathbb{E(|X − b|) = E(|X − m|) + 2 \int_ b^
m
(b − x)f(x)dx}$ , where we assume
that the required expectations exist.

Comment: What were your attempts so far?

Comment: I tried to break the intervals of integration from $- \infty$ to $b$ , $b$ to $m$ and then $m$ to $\infty$ (assuming $b \le m$) (and similarly for theother case .) . But I am not making further progress . I am also unable to use the fact that $m$ is a median .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m>b$. Then
$$
\mathbb E(|X-b|) =$$ 
$$= \int\limits_{-\infty}^b bf(x)dx - \color{red}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^b xf(x)dx} +\int\limits_b^m xf(x)dx - \int\limits_b^m bf(x)dx +\color{blue}{\int\limits_m^\infty xf(x)dx} - \int\limits_m^\infty bf(x)dx
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb E(|X-m|) =$$ 
$$=\! \int\limits_{-\infty}^b mf(x)dx -\! \color{red}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^b xf(x)dx} +\!\int\limits_b^m mf(x)dx -\! \int\limits_b^m xf(x)dx +\color{blue}{\int\limits_m^\infty xf(x)dx} -\! \int\limits_m^\infty mf(x)dx
$$

Subtract the second expression from the first one. 
$$
\mathbb E(|X-b|)-\mathbb E(|X-m|) 
$$
$$
=(b-m)\int\limits_{-\infty}^b f(x)dx +\! 2 \int\limits_b^m xf(x)dx - \int\limits_b^m bf(x)dx -\! \int\limits_b^m mf(x)dx - \!(b-m)\int\limits_m^\infty f(x)dx
$$

Then use that $\int\limits_m^\infty f(x)\,dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^m f(x)\,dx$ since $m$ is the unique median. Replace last integral and subtract it from the first one: 
$$
\mathbb E(|X-b|)-\mathbb E(|X-m|) 
$$
$$
=\color{green}{(b-m)\int\limits_{-\infty}^b f(x)dx} + 2 \int\limits_b^m xf(x)dx - \int\limits_b^m bf(x)dx - \int\limits_b^m mf(x)dx - \color{green}{(b-m)\int\limits^m_{-\infty} f(x)dx}
$$
$$
=(m-b)\int\limits_b^m f(x)dx+ 2 \int\limits_b^m xf(x)dx - \int\limits_b^m bf(x)dx - \int\limits_b^m mf(x)dx = 2\int\limits_b^m (x-b)f(x)\,dx.
$$
Note also that $\mathbb E(|X-b|)$ should be greater than $\mathbb E(|X-m|)$.  Therefore the  integral in r.h.s. of the equality that you prove must be positive. So the right equality should be 
$$
\mathbb{E}(|X − b|) = \mathbb E(|X − m|) + 2 \int_b^m (x − b)f(x)dx.
$$